# Django: module not found while running in Docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, prometheus

I'm running a Django project in a Docker container, and I want to add a module (specifically, [django-prometheus](https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus))

I ran: `pip install django-prometheus` and `docker run -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus` successfully, and I made the necessary alterations to my `settings.py` and `urls.py` files, as [specified in the README](https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus#quickstart)

I then rebuilt the project and restarted it, but it is giving me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_prometheus'`

(full error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
api_1           |     worker.init_process()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
api_1           |     self.load_wsgi()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
api_1           |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
api_1           |     self.callable = self.load()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
api_1           |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
api_1           |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
api_1           |     __import__(module)
api_1           |   File "/usr/src/app/project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
api_1           |     application = get_wsgi_application()
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
api_1           |     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
api_1           |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
api_1           |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
api_1           |     module = import_module(entry)
api_1           |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
api_1           |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
api_1           | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_prometheus'
api_1           | [2019-07-01 12:19:36 +0200] [16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16)
```

)

Prior to me adding this module the project worked perfectly, what am I missing?

Comment: You say you ran `pip install`.  Typically I'd add the library dependency to my `setup.py`/`requirements.txt`, then re-run `docker build`.  Did you do this, or only install the library on your development environment?

Comment: I only installed it in my environment, I'm not sure if there is a `setup.py`/`requirements.txt` in this project (I am not the creator) but I'll see what the equivalent is and add it

Comment: please provide Dockerfile sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you should make sure you have a pip install command. Please have a look at the following example. The prometheus module should be listed in the requirements.txt file.

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -q -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel gcc \
&& apt-get install -q -y vim \
&& apt-get clean 

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to `ADD . /app` and then `RUN pip 3 install -r ...` (assuming the requirements.txt file is part of the project)?

Comment: Thanks, I found the Dockerfile and the dependencies, I got it working :)

Comment: You frequently want to COPY the requirements file separately from the main application code.  Generally the application code changes frequently and the requirements less often, and this sequence allows taking advantage of Docker layer caching to not repeat the package install.

Comment: this has not helped me