# Docker-compose can't import Django (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm very new to Docker, and I've been trying to get a very simple 'Hello World' program to run on docker. No matter what I do I always get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django'

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the terminal output.

```
C:\path\to\app\root>docker-compose up
Creating network "hello-world_default" with the default driver
Creating hello-world_web_1 ... done                                                                                     Attaching to hello-world_web_1
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 10, in main
web_1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1  |     main()
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 16, in main
web_1  |     ) from exc
web_1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
hello-world_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Here's the dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Set environmental variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project 
COPY . /code/
```

And here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

### Edit

This is the content of my `pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
pytz = "==2019.3"
sqlparse = "==0.3.1"
Django = "==2.2.7"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Comment: Why are you copying the files _and_ doing a volume mount?

Comment: I don't know. The code is take from a book called 'Django For Professionals'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: module not found while running in Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834097/django-module-not-found-while-running-in-docker-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
```

you  may use:

```
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY pipfile* /tmp
RUN cd /tmp && pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

this is a snippet from [here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pipenv-docker/)

Comment: Thank you. But this unfortunately did not solve the issue. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I even tried combining the `pip install` command with the previous command using `&&` in the hopes that it might fix the issue by actually installing the packages inside the virtual environment. But I still get the same Django not found error when I run docker-compose.

Comment: @SoroushParsa just use a requrements.txt ?

Comment: also can you post your Pipfile ?

Comment: `Pipfile Pipfile.lock` is the name of your  Pipfile.lock?

Comment: can you tell me where is the path of your `Pipfile.lock`? i think here is the issue

Comment: Thank you very much. 
This is the location to the pipfile.lock file. 
`C:\Users\smnha\OneDrive\Desktop\codes\hello-world\pipfile.lock`

Comment: I have two files for the pipenv. One if `pipfile` and another `pipfile.lock` and I need to copy both apparently.

Comment: I will try only using the requirements.txt. I also edited the answer to include the contents of the `pipfile`

Comment: @SoroushParsa can you try again? seems like your file name is `pipfile` and not `Pipfile`

Comment: I suspect that this is the issue, you have to use to correct name of your files

Comment: @SoroushParsa just check my answer

Comment: the files are actually `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` with capital P. Unfortunately the issue still remains. :(
These are the files: 
`Pipfile  Pipfile.lock  db.sqlite3  docker-compose.yml  dockerfile  hello_project  manage.py  pages  requirements.txt`

Answer (score 6):

Hi I just solved the problem.
After you run

`docker build .`

run the `docker-compose build` instead of `docker-compose up`.

And then finally run `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thank you. I read the same book and had the same problem too.

Comment: @DmytroManzhula No problem. I hope the author updates the content.